# how to fetch data by perticular id in php using my sql

Tags: php

I have list of menu item in that it contain `samsung`, `htc` etc when we click on `samsung` it will display all `samsung mobile` list like  `galaxy note` ,`s3` etc same as when we click on `htc` it will display `htc one` ,`htc desire`
I have problem how to fetch these data by id [image]

Comment: SELECT * FROM MOBILE_TABLE WHERE Mobile_ID = 1

Comment: You can use `WHERE` clause in your query.

Answer (score 0):

**SELECT * FROM MOBILE WHERE ID_MOBILE = {id you want to search};**

Answer (score 0):

It following query should work.(eg. id =1107)
SELECT * FROM  `table` WHERE  `ID`=1107;
Otherwise you can check for Id duplication.

Answer (score 0):

Design your database schema as follows :

```
________________    ___________________
| Manufacturer |    | Products        |
----------------    ------------------- 
|      id      |    |     id          |
| manufacturer |    | manufacturer_id |
----------------    | product_name    | (and so on)
                    -------------------
```

In manufacturer table, you would have Samsung htc etc, and in product table you will have manufacturer id which will be foreign key from Manufacturer table.

```
Query
Select * from products join manufacturer on manufacturer.id = products.manufacturer_id where products.manufacturer_id = { ID To Be Searched}
```